# how to check PayPal user incoming transaction limits

Tags: paypal, limits

i developed a crowdfunding platform.

i would like to check if the paypal account of the person who is submitting a project has any incoming transaction limit.

any idea on how to get it?

thanks

Comment: To my knowledge there is no API to get that sort of information.

Answer (score 1):

There is no public API for that but a good option would be to make sure that the receiving accounts are either Premier or Buisness and are verified accounts. You can use the GetVerifiedStatus API for that. Beyond that, The [PayPal Merchant Services](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/merchant) would be able to provide further assistance if receiving limit issues appear.